# Copy a postgres database without LOCK permissions

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to copy a postgres DB from one server to another, but the credentials I have do not have permission to lock the database so a pg_dump fails.  I have full read/update/insert rights to the DB in question.

How can I make a copy of this database?  I'm not worried about inconsistencies (it is a small database on a dev server, so minimal risks of inconsistencies during the extract)

[edit] Full error:

```
$ pg_dump --username=bob mydatabase > /tmp/dump.sql 
pg_dump: SQL command failed 
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  permission denied for relation sl_node 
pg_dump: The command was: LOCK TABLE _replication.sl_node IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> ERROR:  permission denied for relation sl_node

This is your real problem.

Make sure the user bob has `SELECT` privilege for `_replication.sl_node`. Is that by any chance a Slony system table or something?

Comment: IT's been a few years since I asked this question but from memory yes, there was some Slony stuff that was causing problems.

Comment: DrStalker I have the same problem. I just backup different database. but somehow pg_dump trying to backup one of slony table. Any idea why?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I've same error`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation table2
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.table2 IN ACCESS SHARE MODE`... even I gave all privileges on tab2...

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Fc -c db_name > file_name.pgdump
```

Then create a DB and run pg_restore it:

```
 sudo -u postgres /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_restore -U postgres -d db_name -v file_name.pgdump
```

Comment: `sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Fc -c db_name > file_name.pgdump` This command worked  for me!

Answer (score 9):

`pg_dump` doesn't lock the entire database, it does get an explicit lock on all the tables it is going to dump, though. This lock is taken in "access share mode", which is the same lock level required by a SELECT statement: it's intended just to guard against one of the tables being dropped between it deciding which tables to dump and then getting the data.

So it sounds like your problem might actually be that it is trying to dump a table you don't have permission for? PostgreSQL doesn't have database-level read/update/insert rights, so maybe you're just missing the select privilege from a single table somewhere...

As Frank H. suggested, post the full error message and we'll try to help decode it.

Answer (score 6):

You need `SELECT` permissions (read) on all database objects to make a dump, not `LOCK` permissions (whatever that may be). What's the complete error message when you start `pg_dump` to make a dump?

Comment: I see. It looks like you don't have SELECT permissions for this table. From the manual: "LOCK TABLE ... IN ACCESS SHARE MODE requires SELECT privileges on the target table". http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html You have to get the permissions and try again.

Answer (score 4):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151526

this link helped me a lot. It refers to another one,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS

I first change the ownship to rds_superuser, then paste this piece of code,

```
CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$             
BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN $1; END; $f$;
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser')
FROM (
SELECT nspname, relname
FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) 
WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
      relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
s;
```

thereafter, I am able to dump my whole database.

Comment: this worked for me when i upgraded from postgres 9.5 to 9.6 and started having this issue with RDS

Comment: the first step for me by the way was to `alter schema topology owner to rds_superuser;`

Answer (score 3):

Did you run 'pg_dump' with the correct -U (user who owns that db) ? If yes, then just like other poster said, check the permissions.

HTH

Comment: This was my issue. I tried running it as the `postgres` user, but that wasn't the db owner. Running it as the owning user worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me `-d dbname -n schemaname`

```
pg_dump -v -Fc -h <host> -U <username> -p -d <db_name> -n <schema_name> > file_name.pgdump
```

default schema is `public`

Comment: Worked like a charm.